# How do I do a jQuery media query?

Tags: jquery, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#products .item').addClass('list-group-item');
  $('#list').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#products .item').addClass('list-group-item');
  });
  $('#grid').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#products .item').removeClass('list-group-item');
    $('#products .item').addClass('grid-group-item');
  });
});
```

```css
.glyphicon {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.thumbnail {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.item.list-group-item {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.item.list-group-item:nth-of-type(odd):hover,
.item.list-group-item:hover {
  background: #428bca;
}
.item.list-group-item .list-group-image {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.item.list-group-item .thumbnail {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.item.list-group-item .caption {
  padding: 9px 9px 0px 9px;
}
.item.list-group-item:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #eeeeee;
}
.item.list-group-item:before,
.item.list-group-item:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
.item.list-group-item img {
  float: left;
}
.item.list-group-item:after {
  clear: both;
}
.list-group-item-text {
  margin: 0 0 11px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://bootsnipp.com/dist/bootsnipp.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well well-sm">
    <strong>Category Title</strong>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <a href="#" id="list" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list">
            </span>List</a>  <a href="#" id="grid" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>Grid</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="products" class="row list-group">
    <div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="group list-group-image" src="http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
          <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                        Product title</h4>
          <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
            Product description... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <p class="lead">
                $21.000</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <a class="btn btn-success" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="group list-group-image" src="http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
          <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                        Product title</h4>
          <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
            Product description... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <p class="lead">
                $21.000</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <a class="btn btn-success" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="group list-group-image" src="http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
          <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                        Product title</h4>
          <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
            Product description... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <p class="lead">
                $21.000</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <a class="btn btn-success" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="group list-group-image" src="http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
          <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                        Product title</h4>
          <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
            Product description... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <p class="lead">
                $21.000</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <a class="btn btn-success" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="group list-group-image" src="http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
          <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                        Product title</h4>
          <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
            Product description... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <p class="lead">
                $21.000</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <a class="btn btn-success" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="group list-group-image" src="http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
          <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                        Product title</h4>
          <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
            Product description... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <p class="lead">
                $21.000</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <a class="btn btn-success" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am working on [a snippet I found earlier](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/list-grid-view). The first issue I had is that for this to be a responsive solution I needed to make the list as the default on load which was easy enough, I would just add this as the first line in my `document.ready` function:

```
$('#products .item').addClass('list-group-item');
```

But what if the user decides to click grid view and change the window size? How would I go about adding the `list-group-item` class so that it will change back to list view.

Comment: You really should have used the "Run Code Snippet" for this question, making us go to another site just to see what you're talking about isn't cool and after doing that I still don't know what you mean about *user deciding to click grid view and change the window size*

Comment: @JeremyThompson I added the snippet, for ease of use. This is actually the first time I used that functionality here on stack overflow. I am used to using jsFiddle and pointing to examples. Many apologies!

Comment: Ok I sort of see what you mean now, I think you're going to have to handle this yourself by tapping in to the https://api.jquery.com/resize/ event.

Comment: @Skullomania you should consider a size of the window width to make changes.

Comment: I was able to resolve it...posting the answer now :)

Comment: please do not close this question as I am sure someone else will find it useful!

Comment: Glad you solved it, accept your own answer as the correct one.

Comment: It won't let me until 2 days from now

Comment: Sorry, I didn't knew that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by adding this window resize function

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    var win = $(this);
    if (win.width() <= 767) 
    { 
        $('#products .item').addClass('list-group-item');         
    }
});
```